# How to merge 2 td in a single td only in a row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using jQuery to parse the JSON data and load into a table using AJAX but how can I make the td element merge in a single row only? Don't mind the position of the Header I'm just worried with the data.

My Result:

[image]

This the correct:

[image]

Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FlatType", "Home", new {id = TempData["Id"] })",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    let $thead = $('#myColumns'),
                        $tr = $('<tr>');
                    console.log(data);
                    data.data.forEach(col => {
                        $tr.append($('<th>').html(col === null || col === "" ? 0 : col));
                        console.log(col);
                    });

                    $thead.append($tr);
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FlatTypeById", "Home", new {id = TempData["Id"] })",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    let $tbody = $('#myData');
                    data.data.forEach(row => {
                        let $tr = $('<tr>');
                        $tr.append(row.map(val => {
                            return $('<td>').html(val === null || val === "" ? 0 : val);
                        }));
                        $tbody.append($tr);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

JSON Array Data: This is the COLUMN:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "ID",
            "TYPE",
            "TOTAL",
            "1 bed room",
            "2 bed room"
        ]
    ]
}
```

JSON Array Data: This is the DATA:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "100",
            "Total Transaction Amount",
            "9812355000",
            "23397000",
            "13976000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "No. of units",
            "1268",
            "3",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "(Total sq.ft.)",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. price",
            "7738450",
            "7799000",
            "6988000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. sq.ft.",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. price",
            "25494000",
            "9918000",
            "7318000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. price",
            "5904000",
            "6465000",
            "6658000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Iterate through the data and add the rows 2 by 2 while iterating. If the row%2==0 it still is part of the first row, otherwise create a new td. That's what you probably need.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Read my answer :)

Comment: changed it with a little explanation about the pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to sum all groups together, that you have one row per group.
Sort your data, that is like this:

```
group1
group1
group1
group2
group2
group2
group3
group3
...
```

Then you can iterate over it by using the control break algorithm:

```
var curKey = 0;
var curRow = myArray[curKey];
var newGroup = myArray.someColumn;
var oldGroup = newGroup;

while (typeof curRow !== "undefined") {
    while (newGroup === oldGroup && typeof curRow !== "undefined" {
        // sum your group here
        curKey++;
        curRow = myArray[curKey];
        newGroup = myArray.someColumn;
    }
    oldGroup = newGroup;
}
```

Not tested and also never done in JavaScript before. But yeah, I think you got the feeling. Your data seems to come from a backend. Sorting it in the backend should be easier.

You could also do this example more expensive (and unsorted) in an object oriented way.

Comment: Hello, i think the OP just needs to add the data rows together 2 by 2

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your data, the returned object is an array of objects, each object containing informations. What you might want is to iterate through the array and given that each even positioned object is part of the object that preceeds it, you can do:

Data[0] is in , Data[1] should be in the same td.

If you iterate through the array and control the index iterations with a modulo you can do:

```
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
// data is your ajax data
// data.length is the total length of the data array


// pseudo code

   if(if%2==0)
// If i % 2 == 0 we are at array position that has an even number, the one you want in the same td
// push it to previous td container with .html() or some other method
   my_td_container += "<br />" + data[i-1];
// we create a variable that contains the first td data and add to it a breaklike (<br />) and the new td data

   else
// else --> this odd data is a new td, it's a new row with new data
my_td_container = data[i-1];
// data[i-1] and not data[i] because the even positions are at odd spots, you can refactor this.
}




{
    "data": [
        [
            "100",
            "Total Transaction Amount",
            "9812355000",
            "23397000",
            "13976000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "No. of units",
            "1268",
            "3",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "(Total sq.ft.)",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. price",
            "7738450",
            "7799000",
            "6988000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. sq.ft.",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. price",
            "25494000",
            "9918000",
            "7318000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. price",
            "5904000",
            "6465000",
            "6658000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you, but I don't understand. I'm using jQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo example

```
var jsonDataType = {
                "data": [
                    [
                        "ID",
                        "TYPE",
                        "TOTAL",
                        "1 bed room",
                        "2 bed room"
                    ]
                ]
            }
            var jsonData = {
                    "data": [
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Total Transaction Amount",
                            "9812355000",
                            "23397000",
                            "13976000"
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "No. of units",
                            "1268",
                            "3",
                            "2"
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "(Total sq.ft.)",
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Avg. price",
                            "7738450",
                            "7799000",
                            "6988000"
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Avg. sq.ft.",
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Max. price",
                            "25494000",
                            "9918000",
                            "7318000"
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Max. sq.ft",
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Min. price",
                            "5904000",
                            "6465000",
                            "6658000"
                        ],
                        [
                            "100",
                            "Min. sq.ft",
                            "",
                            "",
                            ""
                        ]
                    ]
                }
var th = "";
        $.each(jsonDataType.data[0], function(index, data){                
            th += "<th>" + data + "</th>";                
        });            
        $('#myColumn').append(th);

        var array = jsonData.data;  
        var tr;
        $.each(array, function(i, data){
            tr = "";
            if(i == 0){
                $.each(data, function(j, result){                
                    tr += "<td>" + result + "</td>";               
                });
                tr += "<tr class='separator' />";
            }
            else{
                $.each(data, function(j, result){  
                    result = result === null || result === "" ? 0 : result            
                    tr += "<td>" + result + "</td>";               
                });
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                tr += "<tr class='separator' />";                                                          
            }

            $('#myBody').append("<tr>" + tr + "</tr>"); 
        })
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/goldenfinger/89pgzg9q/)

Comment: Sir thank you for help I appreciate. But something wrong with the border?